# How to search for a method in C# by attribute?

Tags: c#, interface, attributes

I'm writing a command line utility in C# for .NET Core. I want to allow the user to specify the "action" to run based on a command line parameter. I'm mimicking the PowerShell style command line options, so one of my options is `/Action`. So for example, the user might call the app with `/Action:Update` or `/Action:Reset`.

In C#, I have a method for each action that follows a specific method signature. So, for the `Update` method above, I have a method like this: `public static int Update(Dictionary<string,string> cmdLineArgs, SomeObject obj)`. Each method that is related to a valid parameter on `/Action` has exactly the same signature (same types and variable names).

Right now I just have a `switch` block to call the actions, but this seems incredibly inefficient:

```
int returnValue;
switch (parsedArgs["action"]) {
    case "update":
        returnValue = Update(parsedArgs, o);
        break;
    case "reset":
        returnValue = Reset(parsedArgs, o);
        break;
    ...
    default:
        returnValue=255;
        Console.WriteLine($"No such action {parsedArgs["action"]}.");
        break;
}
```

I've used attributes in the context of Web APIs, and they seem to be a natural starting point to make this more generic. This would ideally result in the situation where adding a new action is as simple as writing its method and adding the correct attribute with the name the user can call it by in the `/Action` switch. My idea is to create a custom attribute (say, `AppActionName`) and then put that attribute on any method that can be called as an action from the command prompt:

```
[AppActionName("update")]
public static int Update(Dictionary<string,string> cmdLineArgs, SomeObject obj)
...

[AppActionName("reset")]
public static int Reset(Dictionary<string,string> cmdLineArgs, SomeObject obj)
...
```

An alternative I've thought about, which would take advantage of type safety, would be to use an interface that defines the action method:

```
public interface IAppAction 
{
    int Run(Dictionary<string,string> cmdLineArgs, SomeObject obj);
}

[AppActionName("update")]
public class UpdateAction : IAppAction
{
    public int Run(Dictionary<string,string> cmdLineArgs, SomeObject obj)
    ...

[AppActionName("reset")]
public class ResetAction : IAppAction
{
    public int Run(Dictionary<string,string> cmdLineArgs, SomeObject obj)
    ...
```

In either case though, what I'm not sure of is how to actually search for, instantiate and run the method.

In the first option (putting the AppActionName directly on the method), I see two problems: 1) having to figure out how to search all methods in the assembly for those with the given attribute, filtering, and then how to actually call the method, and 2) unless I don't know how to do it, I don't think I can enforce the proper method signature using this method.

```
int returnValue;
// in other languages you can get a variable and then call it, but this isn't other languages
// but you might do something like: myMethod = findMethodWithAttribute("update"); returnValue=myMethod(parsedArgs, o);
```

The second option (interface on class implementing interface) seems more type-safe and should be easier to implement (declare an interface-variable and then have it assigned to an instance of the correct class), but I'm still not sure how to actually search for the attribute with the correct name.

```
int returnValue;
// how would you do this correctly?
IAppAction appActionClass = new FindTheClassWithTheAttributeWithParameter("update")();
returnValue = appActionClass.Run(parsedArgs, o);
```

So i think the essence of my question is: "how do I find which method/class has the attribute I defined with the parameter I specified, and then how do I actually instantiate/call the result?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second approach should generally be easier to deal with.

I made an example (which you can run [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SBjVYZ)) for getting the classes that implement the interface and their attribute.

Given something like this:

```
public class AppActionNameAttribute : Attribute 
{ 
    public string Action { get; set; } 

    public AppActionNameAttribute(string action) { Action = action; } 
}

public interface IAppAction 
{
    int Run(Dictionary<string,string> cmdLineArgs, SomeObject obj);
}

[AppActionName("update")]
public class UpdateAction : IAppAction
{
    public int Run(Dictionary<string,string> cmdLineArgs, SomeObject obj) 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Handled :)"); 
        return 1;
    }
}

public class SomeObject { }
```

You can do this:

```
var handlers = typeof(Program).Assembly
     // Get all types in the assembly
    .GetExportedTypes()
     // that are classes and implement IAppAction
    .Where(x => x.IsClass && x.GetInterface("IAppAction") != null)
    .Select(x => new 
    {
        // assuming they are always decorated with [AppActionName]
        Action = x.GetCustomAttribute<AppActionNameAttribute>().Action,
        // get a new instance, assuming parameterless constructor
        Handler = (IAppAction)Activator.CreateInstance(x)
    })
    // and convert it to a Dictionary that you can easily use
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Action, x => x.Handler);
```

Which you can store (preferably in some static field as you don't want to be running this often) and simply use like this:

```
private static Dictionary<string, IAppAction> _handlers = ...;

public static void Main()
{
    string action = Console.ReadLine();

    // you should check the action actually exists in the Dictionary
    var handler = _handlers[action];

    // and then run it:
    Console.WriteLine(handler.Run(someData, otherData));
}
```